# WORD в PHP (mso возможности)

Tags: php, ms-word, веб-программирование

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне необходимо генерировать word странички из под PHP. Погуглив, я увидел несколько вариантов, среди которых создание страниц с использованием mso, т.е. без привязки к Windows. Хотелось бы прояснить два момента:

1) Где можно найти все команды mso, и хотя бы пару примеров.
2) Есть ли вариант проще (не используя платные библиотеки, без привязки к определённой системе).

Заранее очень благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено http://phpword.codeplex.com/ Всем спасибо за абсолютное безучастие в проблеме.